# How to close large holes left in basement concrete floor after remove a coal furnace

Tags: painting

After the removal of a coal furnace in my basement, I was left with two huge holes in the concrete basement floor. Both holes are seeping water onto the basement floor, especially when it rains. How do I repair these holes to stop the water. I've been told to drill thru the concrete floor & run a perforated pipe "across" the floor to allow water to flow in sump pump. The house is old & I'm scared of more holes in concrete floor in order to lay pipe and concerned w/drilling across the floor. But, I've got to stop water pouring out of the holes & get them dry & closed. What to do?

Comment: What does "huge" mean? Actual dimensions, please.

Comment: 4 ft wide & 5 ft long. (An old coal furnace was removed 75yrs old). That should give you an idea how big hole is. I don't yet know how deep, bc base (where stove sat on) is still in the concrete basement floor where water is seeping through.

Comment: Thanks, but you should edit your question to include that information.

Comment: Do you have damp floors or water anywhere else? If the water table was so high the water is coming out of the hole, I'd expect your entire basement floor to be wet as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'd only initially agree with the recommendation you received & that's what most suckers go with. But, if the holes are leaking during & after a rain. Then, you've got outdoor surface problems that would much better address the problem & would be permanent repairs that are eternally free to operate never a future concern, like going away on vacation. Then, the holes can be filled with hydraulic cement.

Plus, your home won't continue to be damaged by the water. **Overwhelmingly**, this issue comes from gutter downspouts that feed into underground drains. The reason for this is because the underground drains create a void against the house & any water that backs up, gathers & saturates that or those areas enters & collects in that void to then drop by gravity to the lowest point. You may find the problem disappears tomorrow, after you call a Plumber in to clear your underground drains.

Otherwise or if you don't have underground drains, you'd need to re-grade the ground around the house (can cost less or the same as the basement's bad idea) to ensure that water runs away from the house rather than toward it. You want to pitch the ground away for 6-feet & even sculpt the ground with natural gullies to direct excess water completely off of the property as quickly as possible.